# Unable to add rows in a PDF table

Tags: java, itext

I tried adding rows under the column. It must display 2 rows which consists of 4 columns each.

The below code provides 1 row and 4 column respectively.

I tried adding `cell1.setRowSpan(1)` under each cell but that doesn't seems to work.

```java
public class report {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\report.pdf"));
            document.open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4); // 4 columns.
            table.setWidthPercentage(100); //Width 100%
            table.setSpacingBefore(10f); //Space before table
            table.setSpacingAfter(10f); //Space after table

            //Set Column widths
            float[] columnWidths = {1f, 1f, 1f , 1f};
            table.setWidths(columnWidths);

            PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
            cell1.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
            cell1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell1.setPaddingLeft(10);
            cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

            PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
            cell2.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
            cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell2.setPaddingLeft(10);
            cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

            PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
            cell3.setBorderColor(BaseColor.RED);
            cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell3.setPaddingLeft(10);
            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell3.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

            PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
            cell4.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
            cell4.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell4.setPaddingLeft(10);
            cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            cell4.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);

            table.addCell(cell1);
            table.addCell(cell2);
            table.addCell(cell3);
            table.addCell(cell4);

            document.add(table);
            document.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {`enter code here`
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code uses itext, your question header says pdfbox. Please decide, what do you want to do?

Comment: @mkl and then someone with >2K reputation jumped in and edited the question. :-D

Comment: oops sry for the misunderstanding! its for itext.

Comment: You have a four-column table and add four cells to create a single row. Now you say *"It must display 2 rows which consists of 4 columns each"*. Have you simply tried adding four more cells for the second row?

Comment: @mkl yes i tried adding `cell1.setRowspan(1);  , cell2.setRowspan(1); cell3.setRowspan(1); cell4.setRowspan(1); ` under each cell.

Comment: *"yes i tried adding ..."* - that's not what I asked. Have you simply tried adding four more cells (probably named `cell5` .. `cell8`) to `table`? Using `setRowspan(1)` does not change anything, each cell already by default claims one row in height (and one column in width).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already defined your table to have 4 columns:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4); // 4 columns.
```

And you have already added 4 cells:

```
table.addCell(cell1);
table.addCell(cell2);
table.addCell(cell3);
table.addCell(cell4);
```

So, just keep adding more cells. The 5th cell you add will automatically become the first cell of row 2.

You can repeat your four `addCell()` statements if you want to see what I mean:

[image]

This just repeats the entire first row.